# VShadow.exe for Vista

Tags: volume-shadow-service

I need the VShadow or its equivalent for Vista (Business).

All the VShadows I am trying are giving errors. I need to use it from Command Prompt.

The procedure entry point ClusterGetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint could not be located in the dynamic link library RESUTILS.dll."

or

VSHADOW.EXE 2.2 - Volume Shadow Copy sample client
Copyright (C) 2005 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
(Option: Create shadow copy set)
ERROR: COM call "CreateVssBackupComponents(&m_pVssObject)" failed.
- Returned HRESULT = 0x80070005
- Error text: Access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

This particular error means that you need to be elevated - run as administrator.

However there are multiple versions of this app for various windows versions.  I'm trying to find one for Windows 8.1 - which I understand uses a whole different engine.  So far I have only found [versions](http://edgylogic.com/blog/vshadow-exe-versions/) - which has a link to a 2010 zip of various versions.

Note - you are using a compiled version of the VSS Tools 7.2 - which says in the documentation only works with Windows Server 2003 (NT 5.2) and Vista is NT 6.0.